# How to insert a full column width block of text in the middle of an indented list

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I'm trying to insert a block of text, set at full line width, in the middle of an indented and nested list item. I've asked the general question, though in my case it involves the `listings` package. What I need is something like this:

```
\item ....

\begin{fullwidth}
\begin{lstlisting)
blah blah too long for indented width but fits in full column width
\end{lstlisting}
\end{fullwidth}

blah blah blah

\item ...
```

I have a stopgap solution using the `figure` envirnoment plus `\FloatBlock` (from `memoir`), but I'm not keen.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution comes from the `listings` package itself: you can use the option `resetmargins=true` in the `lstlisting` environment.

I created a few example just for fun. The one you probably want is the 6th.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fullwidth}% if your really need the fullwidth environment

\begin{document}
    Inside the \verb|itemize| environment:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item example 1

        blah blah too long for indented width but fits in full column width

        \item example 2
        \begin{flushleft}
            blah blah too long for indented width but fits in full column width
        \end{flushleft}

        \item example 3
        \begin{fullwidth}
            blah blah too long for indented width but fits in full column width
        \end{fullwidth}

        \item example 4
        \begin{fullwidth}[skipabove=0pt, skipbelow=0pt]
            blah blah too long for indented width but fits in full column width
        \end{fullwidth}

        \item example 5
\begin{lstlisting}
blah blah too long for indented width but fits in full column width
\end{lstlisting}

        \item example 6 (THIS IS THE ONE)
\begin{lstlisting}[resetmargins=true]
blah blah too long for indented width but fits in full column width
\end{lstlisting}

        \item example 7
        blah blah too long for indented width but fits in full column width
    \end{itemize}

    Outside the \verb|itemize| environment:
\begin{lstlisting}
blah blah too long for indented width but fits in full column width
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Result looks like this:
[image]